# atom.io how to set html autocomplete for templates in .vue files

Tags: html, autocomplete, vuejs2, atom-editor

Atom.io html autocomplete works out of the box for the main index.html.ejs file.

But when in the .vue files where templates are defined (and I want to add an internal div in the template) it does not autocomplete. How do I set the HTML auto-complete to work with this file extension too?

I have vue2-autocomplete package installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned installing autocomplete provide for Vue, but did you install [language syntax for Vue](https://atom.io/packages/language-vue) as well? Once you do, all snippets designed for the scope `text.html.vue` (and the parent scopes) will work.